# 日本語の文章に対してふりがなを付けるRubyのライブラリはありますか？

Tags: ruby

日本語学習者向けのサイトを構築するために漢字を含む日本語の文章にルビをつける機能が欲しいのですが、そのような機能を実装するためのライブラリはありますか？

そのような機能を提供するウェブページはあるのですが、ライブラリやAPIが見つかりませんでした。

http://elephant.ddo.jp/exruby/rubyexpress.html

できれば`ruby`で扱いたいのですが、Linux上で使えるものであればなんでも構いません。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

初めてルビのタグを見ましたが、"漢字"にルビをふるタグは次のようになるようです。タグの構成自体は簡単ですね。MeCabのような形態素解析で、漢字交じりの文を単語に分けて、かつその読みを取得すれば、良いと思います。

```
<ruby>
  <rb>漢</rb>
  <rp>（</rp><rt>かん</rt><rp>）</rp>
</ruby>
<ruby>
  <rb>字</rb>
  <rp>（</rp><rt>じ</rt><rp>）</rp>
</ruby>
```

MeCabに「今日もしないとね。」と入力すると次のような出力が得られます。8番目の要素が読みなので,もし漢字が含まれていれば、8番目の読みをルビとすればよさそうです。

```
% mecab -N2
今日もしないとね。
今日    名詞,副詞可能,*,*,*,*,今日,キョウ,キョー
も      助詞,係助詞,*,*,*,*,も,モ,モ
し      動詞,自立,*,*,サ変・スル,未然形,する,シ,シ
ない    助動詞,*,*,*,特殊・ナイ,基本形,ない,ナイ,ナイ
と      助詞,接続助詞,*,*,*,*,と,ト,ト
ね      助詞,終助詞,*,*,*,*,ね,ネ,ネ
。      記号,句点,*,*,*,*,。,。,。
EOS
```

Comment: 質問主ではありませんが、「組み込む」という入力の場合、「組」に「く」を、「込」に「こ」を振るのがルビとして望ましいように思います。

Comment: それはそうでしょうね。MeCabの精度はとりあえず置いておいて、漢字とひらがなが混ざった単語とその読みが与えられた時に、漢字の部分だけ読みを切り出せばいけそうです。

Answer (score 5):

ライブラリではありませんが、Rubyとmecabコマンドでルビを処理してみました。入力形式はプレーンテキスト、出力形式はRe:VIEWの@<ruby>{}形式で。

```
def apply_yomi w, y
  wk = w.tr 'ぁ-ん', 'ァ-ン'
  return w if wk == y
  c = %r[#{Regexp.quote(wk).gsub(/\p{Han}+/, '(.+)')}].match(y).captures
  w.gsub(/\p{Han}+/) {|m| "@<ruby>{#{m},#{c.shift}}" }
end

IO.popen(%w(mecab --node-format=%m\t%f[7]\n --unk-format=%m\t%m\n
            --eos-format=\n)).each_line do |s|
  if s.chomp!.empty?
    puts
  else
    print apply_yomi *s.split(/\t/)
  end
end
```

実行例。

```
$ echo '我輩は猫である' | ruby ruby-ruby.rb
@<ruby>{我輩,ワガハイ}は@<ruby>{猫,ネコ}である
$ echo '本体に組み込むボード' | ruby ruby-ruby.rb
@<ruby>{本体,ホンタイ}に@<ruby>{組,ク}み@<ruby>{込,コ}むボード
```

Comment: すっごい簡潔なコードですね。ひとつ新しいテクニックを覚えました。

Comment: 漢字を`(.+)`に置き換えて対応するかなを取り出すのおもしろいですね。一つの形態素の中でひらがな部分が漢字の読みとかぶると取り出すかながズレそうですが、そんな単語あるんだろうか…。

Comment: 同意。動的計画法か？何て思っていました。